# JSON serialization is very slow when compared to XML

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi service that I need to access from web app

If I call the webapi url directly (e.g. /api/scrccc/32) it returns data in less then 5 sec, but when called from jquery, it takes more then 5 minutes (!!!) minutes

My ajax call is

```
j$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: '/api/scrccc/' + id + '?dt=' + new Date().getTime(),
   error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
       //....         
   },
   success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
       //....
   }
});
```

This happens with javascript console (firebug) open or closed, and in Chrome and FF

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

**EDIT:**

Here are the timings in Chrome with Jquery call:

[image: Timimgs in Chrome - with jquery]

and the timings in Chrome with direct access to url in address bar

[image: Timimgs in Chrome - direct url call]

... and timimgs in browser with timestamp also

[image: Timimgs in Chrome - direct url call with timestamp param]

**EDIT - June 1**

I realized there is a difference between calling the webapi from ajax and from browser's address bar:
- ajax call requests response as json
- browser requests response as XML

So I tested both requests in Postman, with json and xml response and the findings puzzled me: request with xml response took 1261 ms while json response took 47000 ms (!!!)

(The timings shown in Chrome console were with local IIS Express, while latest timings shown in Postman are with real app on real web server over internet, that's why they are different, but the scale remains)

[image: XML response]

[image]

So, indeed, the problem is at the server side, as some suggested, but not in the actual application code providing data, but instead at the serialization point.

My Webapi is 2.1 (version 5.1.2), and Json.Net version 6.0.3 (both are latest versions)
I have no special settings to use any particular json serializer, so, as I know, WebApi uses Json.Net.

Any idea what could cause such a HUGE difference in serialization time?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing the serverside code that actually takes five minutes to caugh up a result is more interesting than the ajax call ?

Comment: Look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see what timing info it offers.  Might give you a clue where to look next.

Comment: @adeneo, it's not serverside code - if I call the webapi url directly in browser's address bar or with a rest client as Chrome's Postman, it returns json data in 5 seconds

Comment: And it's not the general ajax function you posted either, as that has been used by millions of developers without issue, so something else is going on, and we can't really help you with this other than stating the obvious, there's nothing wrong with jQuery's ajax..

Comment: And looking at your screen grabs, getting 135kb took 5.4 minutes. The issue clearly isn't on the clientside, are you sure the cachebusting querystring doesn't affect the server somehow ?

Comment: When you test in the browser directly, are you including the dt={timestamp} param with a unique timestamp?

Comment: It is clear from the timings that the browser is sitting there waiting for 5 minutes for a response to come back from the server.  I agree with gwcoffey that you should compare direct vs. jQuery with the exact same URLs so you can remove that difference.

Comment: @gwcoffey is correct, your URLs are different - include the same `dt` parameter and I bet you will see the same amount of time.

Comment: Also try to make ajax GET request without jQuery with native XMLHttpRequest and see what happens.

Comment: @gwcoffey, thanks for checking, but dt param doesn't make any difference, it's not handled on server, it's just for caching purpose

Comment: @dfsq, thanks, I already noticed that json vs xml it's what makes the difference - see the new edits

Comment: @aderno, you were right - the issue was on server side code. I discovered that I had a calculated property in the model, which, being expensive, was calculated first access. It didn't made any difference on single object access, but made the huge difference when loading 500+ objects at once. Regarding XML response being very fast, the reason was XML serializer didn't picked that property on serialization (maybe because it was RO). Thanks again to everybody for your time and your suggestions

Comment: @NicholasDynan - The issue here was a peculiarity in OP's code (detailed in the comment right before this one), and not a problem that people are likely to run into in general. This question probably should have been closed as "does not reproduce". If you have a specific question about an issue you are encoutering, I suggest posting it as a new question.

Comment: @bzamfir Since this question is still open and there's now a large bounty on it, could you post an answer with details about what was causing the issue so that others might benefit from it?

Comment: Can you provide us c# code to analyze how you return values from your "scrccc" metod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, thanks to all who took the time to loot at this.
As I posted in comment to *@adreno*, the problem was with an expensive calculated property, loaded on first access.

The property was in an class defined in BL, which was used in various places, so at first I didn't thought to check it.

Why that property was excluded from serialization by XML serialization? I don't know, and due to time constraints, I didn't had either the time or a particular interest to investigate further (since it's not an open api, and we didn't needed XML output).

Comment: Yes, because I discovered and fixed the root of the problem - expensive property

Answer (score 1):

How do you serialize the JSON?, what library are you using, I would try just Gson first in case that you are using Jackson or another library that your framework is using.

like I said render a String

```
String myjson = "";
Gson gson = new Gson();
myjson = gson.toJson(myuser);//myuser is my java object

return myjson
```